# How to populate a binary tree in C from an input file text

Tags: c, file, pointers, tree, scanf

i'm working on this class project. First point is to to acquire inputs from a txt file and store them in a tree. Second point is to allow the user to search in that tree the stored values by the first element of every column (which is a date). Third point is to allow the user to delete values from a specific date.

First of all here's the input file format, as you can see there's a date (year,month,day, hour), a value #1 and #2:

- 2019060908 1.2 3.4
- 2019060909 5.6 7.8
- ....

**I do need help on the very first step. Which is acquire inputs from that txt file and store them in the tree.** Let's start by say that i'm not sure what kind of tree i should be using.

Here's my try of the tree struct

```
    typedef struct my_bt
 {
       char value;                  
       struct my_bt  *left_p, *right_p;     
   } my_bt_t;
```

The **main function** is basically a function that acquire all the three values in the first row of my txt file, that's where i started:

```
int main (void) {

   int value;
   char str1[10], str2[10];

   FILE *file_input;

   file_input = fopen ("file_input", "r+");

   fscanf(file_input, "%d %s %s", &value, str1, str2);

   printf("Read String1 %d \n", value );
   printf("Read String2 %s \n", str1 );
   printf("Read String3 %s \n", str2 );

   fclose(file_input);

   /* function call */

   insert_in_bt(**root_p, value);

   return(0);
}
```

Then i tried to implement a function to insert a value in a tree, here it is:

```
int insert_in_bt(my_bt_t **root_p,
                    int value)
{
    int insert;
    my_bt_t *node_p,
              *father_p,
              *new_p;


    for (node_p = father_p = *root_p;
        ((node_p != NULL) && (node_p -> value != value ));
        father_p = node_p, node_p = (value < node_p->value)?
                    node_p ->left_p:
                    node_p ->right_p);

    if (node_p != NULL)
        insert = 0;
    else
    {
        insert = 1;
        new_p = (my_bt_t *)malloc(sizeof(my_bt_t));
        new_p -> value = value;
        new_p -> left_p = new_p -> right_p = NULL;
        if (node_p == *root_p)
            *root_p = new_p;
        else
            if (value < father_p -> value)
            father_p -> left_p = new_p;
           else
            father_p -> right_p = new_p;
    }
    return(insert);
}
```

I know it's kinda messy and i know theres a few mistakes cause **here's what the compiler says**:

- **error**: ‘root_p’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     insert_in_bt(**root_p, value);
                               ^
- **note**: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
- **warning**: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]    father_p = node_p, node_p = (value
  < node_p->value)?
- **warning**: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     father_p -> left_p = new_p;
                     ^
- **warning**: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     father_p -> right_p = new_p;
                     ^
- **warning**: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
     fscanf(file_input, "%d %s %s", &value, str1, str2);

If i could make these two functions "collaborate", then i can reiterate them  to populate the tree (if that does make sense). There's something wrong with pointers and types, but i feel like i took the wrong path to solve the problem and went astray, so i'm really open to a new point of view or a new solution. I know there's a lot of stuff but people told me to be very very specific!

**Thank you all!**

Comment: Try fixing your compilation errors in the order in which they're reported.  The very first one is obvious:  You have a reference to a variable `root_p` in your `main` function, but it is not declared there.  You need to figure out what you want for that.  Do you want a variable in `main` called `root_p`?  If so, then you need to declare it and assign to it.  If not, then you need to remove the reference.  Keep going like this until you can at least get the code to compile.

Comment: If you want to search in the tree, you should consider building a Binary Search Tree.